# dvips to convert a bitmap image lines but i need normal strokes

Tags: dvips

I follow below mentioned method to convert a pdf document.

latex `filename.tex` then convert dvi to ps `dvips filename.ps`

I am using some required print distiller setting to convert a PDF document.

My problem is table rules like `toprule bottomrule` all of them to be converted bitmap images

Please see the below mentioned pitstop report figures.[image]

See the Warning error. This error should be avoided.

[image]

Current output all lines to be converted into **bitmap images**. But my required output is all lines to be converted in to **strokes**.

Any option is used to convert during the conversion process `dvips filename.dvi` command. Please advice.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't compile with `pdflatex`?

Comment: dvips has -X and -Y command line options to specify horizontal and vertical resolution, you could try setting those to a bigger number than preflight is complaining about

Comment: Specific pdf setting is provided. I should used to create the specific settings version PDF. By default pdflatex is not supported this settings. So i create the ps and then pdf is doing specific distiller settings.

Comment: If i used pdflatex i am not getting Updated version acrobat XI pdfs. Please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a very high resolution with -D option, e.g.

```
dvips -D 4000 filename.dvi
```

default is 600. You can change default resolution in config.ps file.

Comment: the above command is working excellent. Thank you